# I want to add multi language support to my react application which uses AWS Lambda Serverless Infrastructure in the backend

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, internationalization

I tried i18n but it can make only static translations. I want the page to translate dynamically during runtime . Do not want to use Google Translate. need idea or approach for the same.